# Enterprise Library insert row example

Tags: enterprise-library

I'm using MS Enterprise Library 5.0. I'm having trouble getting started. Looking for a example to insert one row into a table with 15 columns? All i can find are complicated examples using dataset.

Is there a simple sample code to insert one row into a table using enterprise library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this article on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/MS-EntLib-DataAccess1.aspx). It is making use of 4.1 and using a stored proc however it would be trivial to change that stored proc to a SQL string which should get what you want.